# Child process of .net core application is using parent's configuration file

Tags: configuration, .net-core, console-application

I have 2 .NET Core 2.0 console applications. The first application calls the second one via System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(). Somehow the second app is inheriting the development configuration information located in the appsettings.development.json of the first app.

I execute the first app by running either **dotnet run** in the root of the project or **dotnet firstapp.dll** in the folder where the DLL exists. This is started from in Powershell.

Both apps are separate directories. I'm not sure how this is happening.

***UPDATE WITH CODE***

The apps reside in

```
C:\Projects\ParentConsoleApp
C:\Projects\ChildConsoleApp
```

This is how I call the app from parent application:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("dotnet", "C:\\projects\\ChildConsoleApp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.0\\publish\\ChildConsoleApp.dll" + $" -dt {DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}");
```

This is how I load the configuration from JSON (this is same in both apps):

```
class Program
{
    private static ILogger<Program> _logger;

    public static IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    public static IServiceProvider Container { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterServices();

        _logger = Container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting GICMON Count Scheduler Service");

        Configure();

        // At this point DBContext has value from parent! :(
        var repo = Container.GetService<ICountRepository>();
            var results = repo.Count(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContext"), args[0]);


    }
    private static void Configure()
    {
        string envvar = "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT";
        string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(envvar);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(env))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "Environment variable not found.");
        _logger.LogInformation($"DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT environment variable value is: {env}.");
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(env)) // environment == "Development"
        {
            builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true);
        }
        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    private static void RegisterServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
        services.AddLogging((builder) => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        loggerFactory.AddNLog(new NLogProviderOptions { CaptureMessageTemplates = true, CaptureMessageProperties = true });
        loggerFactory.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
        Container = serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer with the code that launches second applicatio (exact call to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`). Also please add the code that loads configuration in the second application.

Comment: @CodeFuller Updated question with code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that you set base path for configuration builder to the current working directory:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
```

When you create a child process, it inherits current directory from the parent process (unless you set current directory explicitly).

So the child process basically uses JSON configs from the directory of parent process.

There are several possible fixes:

1. Do not set base path to the current directory.

   When the application is launched, you don't know for sure that current directory will match directory where application binaries are placed.
   If you have an exe file in `c:\test\SomeApp.exe` and launch it from the command line while the current directory is `c:\`, then current directory of your application will be `c:\`. In this case, if you set base path for configuration builder to current directory, it will not be able to load configuration files.

   By default, configuration builder loads config files from `AppContext.BaseDirectory` which is the directory where application binaries are placed. It should be desired behavior in most cases.

   So just remove `SetBasePath()` call:

   ```
   var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
   ```
2. If for some reason you want to set the base path of configuration builder to the current directory, then you should set correct current directory for the launched child process:

   ```
   var childDllPath = "C:\\projects\\ChildConsoleApp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.0\\publish\\ChildConsoleApp.dll";
   var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet", childDllPath + $" -dt {DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}")
   {
       WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(childDllPath),
   };

   Process.Start(startInfo);
   ```

Comment: "When you create a child process, it inherits current directory from the parent process (unless you set current directory explicitly)." -> Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @CodeFuller explained, the reason is that both apps read the same `appsettings.{env}.json` file. For simplicity, you may just rename the config file (and the corresponding name in `.AddJsonFile`) for the second app to prevent any possible overrides.

See, when you register JSON file as a configuration source by `.AddJsonFile`,  configuration API allows you to use whatever file name you need and
you are not forced to use the same `$"appsettings.{env}.json"` pattern for both applications.